# Algebraic Manipulations in Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon Test Statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paired-data

### Given

Let $\Delta > 0 $ be positive real number. Consider the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney upper tail test $H_0: \Delta \leq 0 \,\,\, \text{vs} \,\,\, H_a: \Delta > 0$ aimed at testing the difference between the distribution $F$ of $X$ and the distribution $G$ of $Y$, based on $X_1,\cdots, X_m$ and $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n$. The distribution-free Rank Sum Test created by Wilcoxon, Mann and Whitney can be summarized simply as follows:
Let $N = m + n$, and let $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n$  denote the ranks assigned to $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n$ respectively in the joint sample of size $N=m+n$. Define the following statistic
$$
W = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n{S_j}.
$$
Now, recall that the Mann-Whitney statistic is given by
$$
U = \sum_{i=1}^m{\sum_{j=1}^n{h(X_i,Y_j)}},
$$
where
$$
h(X_i,Y_j) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \texttt{if} \,\, X_i < Y_j, \\
0 & \texttt{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.
$$

### Questions

1. Show that: $ \mathbb{E}_0(W) = \frac{n(m+n+1)}{2} $
2. Show that: $ \mathbb{V}_0(W) = \frac{mn(m+n+1)}{12} $
3. Show that: $ W = U + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $

Assuming 1. and 4. have been proven:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
W                  &= U + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
\mathbb{E}_0(W)    &= \mathbb{E}_0(U) + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
                   &= \frac{mn}{2} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\
                   &= \frac{mn + n(n+1)}{2} \\
                   &= \frac{mn + n^2 + n}{2} \\
\frac{n(m+n+1)}{2} &= \frac{n(m + n + 1)}{2} \hspace{1em} {\Large \checkmark}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

4. Show that: $ \mathbb{E}_0(U) = \frac{mn}{2} $
5. Show that: $ \mathbb{V}_0(U) = \frac{mn(m+n+1)}{12} $

I don't even know how to begin trying to answer this. Could someone help me get the ball rolling (without giving me the answers)? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: These results cannot be derived from just the information given.  I believe you have to adopt the null hypothesis $H_0:\Delta=0$ and make (several) additional assumptions that imply the distribution of $W$ under this null is the same as if $m$ values from the set of ranks $1,2,\ldots, n+m$ had been randomly assigned to $X.$

Comment: So, I'm thinking that $\text{mean}(W) = \frac{S_1+S_2+...+S_j+...+S_n}{n}$, but I have no idea how that could possibly equal $\frac{n(m+n+1)}{2}$. I can make similar algebraic substitutions, but they all seem like the _wrong_ approach.

Perhaps @sal-mangiafico can offer some more help for me today?

Comment: Your first expression for the mean makes no sense, because the mean is a number whereas the expression the right hand side is a random variable.  Use linearity of expectation and the fact that $E(S_i)=(1+n)/2$ (obviously) for any $i.$

Comment: I have no idea what "_Use linearity of expectation_" means.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22linearity+of+expectation%22

Comment: @whuber I came up with a way to answer Question 3 (see above). I'm still a little lost on _linearity of expectation_, though. I understand that $\mathbb{E}_0(W)$ should be the average of $W$ for an _infinite_ number of $W$, but where does $\mathbb{E}(S_i)$ come into play?